# How to pass variable file path to SQL*Loader on Linux

Tags: java, oracle, sql-loader

I'm creating .csv file and placing it in one location.

```
String location = "/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv";
```

Using exact path working fine on Windows but I need it to work on Linux client too.

```
String location = "$XXFIN_TOP\\12.0.0\\bin\\xe.csv";
```

If I'm using relevant path on Linux it is not working, showing Error

> SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open  file(/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv)
>   SQL*Loader-553: file not found
>   SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory

Comment: first string uses slashes, the other one backslashes. Any reason?

Comment: fist one is working fine but I don't want to pass exact path so how to set relevant path please help me

Comment: do you mean relative instead of relevant?

Comment: this is exact path right String location = "/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv";        I'm trying to pass relevant path for Linux machine     first one for  windows

Comment: @Babu - what Sebas is saying is that your relative path declaration, as you have posted here, uses **backslashes** . That's the one you say isn't working. So maybe that's worth looking at in your code.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to say which path you're using for which operating system.

Comment: Sry for all in windown Machine I'm using String location = "/APPL_TOP2/IMDD/apps/apps_st/appl/xxfin/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv";                    Client is asking any option to pass relevant path client machine is Linux So how can I give relevant path based on windows path

Answer (score 0):

> " Client is asking any option to pass relevant path client machine is Linux"

Paths in Linux have slashes which go the other way. So it should be this:

```
$XXFIN_TOP/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv
```

Comment: Not working Error Occured$XXFIN_TOP/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv (No such file or directory)java.io.FileNotFoundException: $XXFIN_TOP/12.0.0/bin/xe.csv (No such file or directory)